Rider: Unable to find Azurite executable
I recently downloaded Jetbrains Rider (2024.1.2; Build #RD-241.15989.179, built on May 6, 2024). I have the latest node.js LTS installed and did a npm i azurite -g. In the settings there is the option to use Azurite. There for the Azurite executable path I have referenced C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azurite\dist\src\azurite.js. (unfortunately the screenshot still shows without 'Roaming')
When I try to run it, I am getting the error Unable to find Azurite executable. What am I doing wrong? I have found this Rider Support Ticket, but it didn't really help.

The file does exist.


Here's my win11 env


Got it working, posting here in case it might be helpful for others. The correct path is:
C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\npm\azurite.cmd
I had to include the cmd extension otherwise it didnt work.


Thanks for detailed explanations. I noticed that azurite installation was missing. So I had to do:
npm install -g azurite
